# OSX Cocoa App: AVFoundation Screen Capture Callback is not called after display goes to sleep

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, avfoundation

I'm working on a Cocoa app on OSX which captures the screen in pseudo real-time.

For some reason the screen capture callback which looks like this:

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
```

isn't called after the display goes to sleep (System Preferences -> Energy Saver) AND the display has been taken out of "sleep mode" again by the user. Is there a reason for that? And how do I prevent it (i.e. fix it!) ???

I set it up like this:

```
/****** This code snippet is used to set up the capture callbacks********************** */
    /* Create a capture session. */
    captureSession = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
    if ([captureSession canSetSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh])
    {
        /* Specifies capture settings suitable for high quality video and audio output. */
        [captureSession setSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh];
    }

    /* Add display as a capture input. */
    // selectedDisplayId is defined prior to calling this code snippet */
    captureScreenInput = [[AVCaptureScreenInput alloc] initWithDisplayID:selectedDisplayId];
    if ([captureSession canAddInput:captureScreenInput])
    {
        [captureSession addInput:captureScreenInput];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Could not add main display to capture input\n");
    }

    AVCaptureVideoDataOutput *output = [[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput alloc] init];

    [captureSession addOutput:output];

    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("myQueue", NULL);
    [output setSampleBufferDelegate:self queue:queue];

    output.alwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames = TRUE;

    output.videoSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject: [NSNumber numberWithInt:kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA] forKey:(id)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey];

    /* Start the capture session. */
    printf("*** Start capture session ***\n");
    [captureSession startRunning];
    /****** ********* This code snippet is used to set up the capture callbacks **********************/
```

So in short, screen capture callback is called repetitively as expected while the display is on. When the display goes to sleep and the user takes the display out of "sleep mode" again, the callback doesn't resume being called. How do I solve that?

Thanks

I'm on MAC OSX 10.8.5

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough with my question. I'm NOT trying to capture the screen when the display goes to sleep. What I'm trying to accomplish is that the callback IS called AFTER the user has woken up the display. The problem I'm describing (or at least trying to), is that the callback stops being called after the display has gone to sleep AND the user has woken the display up from sleep.

Comment: Much better, thanks for clarifying. On iOS the app gets app state notifications (will resign active, did enter background). Are there similar app-state notifications you can listen for? My guess is OSX (as iOS) just sends an app-state notification and nothing else.